# Is there a way to run asynchronously typescript class methods without blocking the main thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, outlook

I am making an app that gets attachments from certain messages from my outlook mail. I have a Mongodb to store info from these attachments in. The problem is that the process of receiving these attachments is quite time-taking, that's why I want to have it working in another thread apart from the main one, in case I would want to cancel it or track it's progress somehow.

Now I know that the main problem of nodejs is that it's single-threaded. But nevertheless I found several modules, like Bull, Webworker-threads or workerpool that might help me with this, and of course I have tried to use Node's ChildProcess. The main issue with those modules is that they can either run async code from a file or use static functions that doesn't depend on current data (as far as I understood from examples and docs). But in my situation I can't use in this way.

The question is - is there a way for me without changing my whole architecture of code to run asynchronously the class methods?

```js
//sync.running.controller.ts
import { ConfigServiceFuncs } from "../config.service";
import { SyncRunningService } from "./sync.running.service";

export class SyncRunningController {
  constructor(private readonly configService : ConfigServiceFuncs, private     readonly syncService : SyncRunningService) {}

  //Method that runs when a Put request is made

  @Put
    //I want to have it working in another thread so that I could send another requests, like Delete or Get

  async StartUpdate() {
    this.syncService.startSync();
  }
}



//sync.running.service.ts

import {GetMessagesFromMail } from "./code.js";
@Injectable()
export class SyncRunningService {

  constructor(@Inject('SOME_MODEL') private readonly syncModel :  Model<SomeModel>, private readonly configService : ConfigServiceFuncs){}


  async syncFunc(){

    this.syncDatabase();

  }
  
  async SyncDatabase(){

    databaseObjects = await GetMessagesFromMail();
    /*
     Then goes the code for adding info to database 
    */

}

    }
  
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have costly loops, you might define a function to generate a "yielding" promise: `const y = () => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 0))` and perform your work in an `async` function, occasionally calling `await y()`, to yield back to the rest of your program. Things will still be "lumpy", but you won't freeze everything this way.

Comment: Can you clarify what this generator is doing exactly? I am not really good with Promises.

Comment: Updated code to make more clear how it works.

Comment: As far as I understood, the logic is this: When my Put request is made I run a function StartUpdate(). In there I can use generators with yield to do some code of my function syncFunc() in SyncRunningService, then come back to StartUpdate, then back to syncFunc() to do another part of this function from the line I left it. But the problem is that I still have to wait till the StartUpdate() func is finished so that I can use other requests to cancel my update, for example Delete request to cancel my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a way to deal with this problem. Thanks to **mongoose** https://mongoosejs.com/ I was able to communicate with mongoDB via it's functions. 
Thus I was able to create a standalone .ts file, create classes to access Controller's and Service's methods.

Next I used Nodejs's Child_Process fork(), and this way I had a working async functionality.

I think the main issue with this solve is repetitive code, this way we will need to update schemas each time they are updated in the rest code.

```js
//sync.ts - standalone file
//imports
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://path/to/database', {useNewUrlParser : true});
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open',function(){
  //functions to create models
  function CreateModel1(){
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //declare your schema here
    });
    var model = mongoose.model('Model1',schema);
    return model;
  }
  /*
  same function for Model2
  */

  var model1 = CreateModel1();
  var model2 = CreateModel2();

  //declare class instances for your service class, if any
  var syncServiceClass = new SyncRunningService(/* ... */);
  (async function(){
    syncServiceClass.syncFunc();
  })();
}

//.controller.ts
/*
  ...
*/
async StartUpdate(){
   const child_process = require('child_process');

   var worker_process = child_process.fork(__dirname + "/sync.ts");

   worker_process.on('close',function(){
     console.log("child process was finished");
     return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically you've reinvented BullJS (https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) but with MongoDB instead of Redis. Vehicle this will do the job (somewhat), I'd recommend you switch to a full featured queue manager like BullJS (or RabbitMQ, Kafka or one of the other million queue providers).